How to Retrieve Purchased Subscription Details in React Native (Expo) Using Superwall?
I'm building a React Native app using Expo and managing subscriptions with the Superwall SDK. I can successfully retrieve the user's subscription status with the following code:
Superwall.shared
    .getSubscriptionStatus()
    .then((status) => console.log(status));

This gives me the current subscription status (e.g., active, inactive), but I need to determine which specific subscription the user has purchased (e.g., monthly, yearly plan).
How can I retrieve detailed information about the specific subscription plan a user has purchased in React Native (Expo) using the Superwall SDK? Is there a method or approach that allows me to get details such as the plan name, duration, or other relevant information about the subscription?
What I’ve Tried:
I tried using Superwall.shared.getUserAttributes() to retrieve additional details, but it didn't return any useful data related to the subscription plan.

You can extend the SuperwallDelegate and use its handleSuperwallEvent(eventInfo:) function to get the product id of the purchased product from the transactionComplete event which is fired when a user completes a transaction. Here's an example of how to do this:
export class MySuperwallDelegate extends SuperwallDelegate {
  handleSuperwallEvent(eventInfo: SuperwallEventInfo) {
    switch (eventInfo.event.type) {
      case EventType.transactionComplete:
        const productId = eventInfo.event.product.productIdentifier;
        // Do something with the purchased product id
      default:
        break;
    }
  }

  // Other methods here
}

const delegate = new MySuperwallDelegate();
Superwall.shared.setDelegate(delegate);

Hope that helps!
